# Double loop to get Ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I want to get all the tasks name as task id, where array of tasks are stored in array of groups.
I am trying to get it in ng-options directive of angularJS. Here is http://jsfiddle.net/753YB/16/ link for quick edit. 
thanks in advance! I know in single array it is `task.Id as task.Name for task in Tasks` but my tasks are nested in groups so I need tasks in all group.

```
$scope.Groups = [{
        Name: 'a1',
        Id: 1,
       Tasks:[{Name: 'Some Name' Id: 1},{Name: 'Some Name 2' Id: 2}]
    }, {
        Name: 'c2',
        Id: 2,
        Tasks:[{Name: 'Some Name 3' Id: 3},{Name: 'Some Name 4' Id: 4}]
    },
       {
        Name: 'c2',
        Id: 3,
        Tasks:[{Name: 'Some Name 3' Id: 5},{Name: 'Some Name 4' Id: 6}]
    }];
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible with this model structure. You might have to flatten your model into a task list.

Comment: +1 runTarm it's not going to work, if the structure won't change to often you might extract tasks into separate array, and if you don't have to use ng-options you might try to achieve it with ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten your data structure with the following function:

```
function flattenArray(array, fn)  {
   var output = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      var result = fn(array[i]);
      if (result) 
         output = output.concat(result);
   }
   return output;
}
```

Call the function by passing it an array and an item callback. The callback returns the sub-array.

```
$scope.Groups = flattenArray(groups, function(item) { 
     return item.Tasks;
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27UGZ/2/)